# How to link to an archive-special.php from a custom front-page template?

Tags: custom-post-type-archives

It seems to me that I am trying to do something really simple : linking to a custom archive page. I'm almost ashamed that I'm struggling with this !

I already created the custom post type (books), with a template for the archive page archive-books.php. Now, my goal is to create a link to go the this archive page. Something like this : All Books

The Link will be in my front-page, where I have different loops that are calling different contents.

- Loop 1 => Title : Ongoing Events / Content : All the Ongoing Events
- Loop 2 => Title : Future Events / Content : All the Future Events
- Loop 3 => Title : Recent Books / Content : The Last 5 Books registered

Specifically, I want to put the link just after the title, like this :

Loop 3. The Title / Link : All books / Content …

I know how to achieve this "the amateur way", by using this piece of code :

```
<a href="https://example.com">All books</a>
```

But I suppose that there is a "professional way" in which I can use some template tags

My first choice was to try with

```
<?php post_type_archive_title(); ?>
```

but it is not doing anything, or I don't know how to set the parameters.

Someone has an idea about this ?

Comment: There's the [`get_post_type_archive_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type_archive_link/) function.

Comment: @t31os that is exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be dependent upon how you created the custom post type.  If you actually just created a post type called `book` and didn't create any rewrites then all you have to do is link to `/book`.  There's nothing amateur about doing it this way...that's how WordPress is designed.  The only thing I might suggest as a bit amateur (in a most helpful way though) is not adding a prefix to your post type.

You should try creating your post type something specific. Example: `gd_book`.  Then use rewrite to change the slug to `book`.  You can do this by adding this line to your $args:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'books'),
```

(make sure to visit your permalinks page in settings to refresh this though)

If you did add a rewrite when you created your CPT (or just now) then you'll need to use that new slug.

your link would be www. gagdetssite .com/books.

Your code could be `<a class="btn" href="/books">All Books</a>` if you put it in pages directly.

If you're coding it as part of the project you could also use: `get_post_type_archive_link('gd_book')`.

Comment: It's good to know that this is not amateur ! I really like the way you use /books to declare the reference, instead of the whole hyperlink, as I did... Also you saw it right about the way I created my custom post type. Its name is 'books' (but in spanish 'libros'). I am definitely interested in learn and apply the best practices, so I will change the name of my cpt and create rewrites to preserve the permalinks ! I have to verify if there is no conflict, because I did a lot of connections with the plugin 'post2post'